# Execute a function of a Fragment inside a ViewPager, from a Fragment Parent button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

class **BurnerAssembly** extends Fragment

BurnerAssembly is the class of the fragment from where the function would be executed,the following code generates the necessary fragments for each object in the array *title*, and the button *btnNext* that would execute the function

```
private String[]title={"Valvula de Combustible", "Ventilador", "Trasformador de Ignicion", "Electrodos", "Cable de Alta", "Boquilla de combustible", "Reguladora de Combustible", "Filtro de combustible", "Tuberia de combustible", "Manometros de Combustible", "Swich de Presion"};


public void loadViewPager(){
    adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    for(int i=0; i<title.length; i++){
        adapter.addFragment(newInstance(title[i], dataForm[i]), i);
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pagerListener);
}

//metodo que genera los sliders
private SliderFragment newInstance(String title, String dataForm){
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("title", title);
    bundle.putString("dataForm", dataForm);

    SliderFragment fragment=new SliderFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resetForm();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Obtener Promocion",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

class **MyViewPagerAdapter** extends FragmentPagerAdapter

All fragments are saved in the *list* array

```
List<Fragment> list=new ArrayList<>();

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, int position){
    if(position == list.size())
        list.add(fragment);
    else
        list.add(position, fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

class **SliderFragment** extends Fragment

this is the function i need to execute

```
public void resetFrom(){
    btnB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_btn_unselected);
    btnB.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.btnUnselected));
    btnR.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_btn_unselected);
    btnR.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.btnUnselected));
    btnM.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.style_btn_unselected);
    btnM.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.btnUnselected));

    spinnerObservations.setSelection(0);

    observation.setText("NA");
}
```

Comment: When you need call resetFrom?

Comment: I need to call the reset Form, from a button that is outside the viewpager, and that it resets the view of the fragment shown inside the viewpager, I hope I have made myself understood.